# To display dropdown in Chips Autocomplete component when it is touched

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using **Chips Autocomplete** component, when I touched the  **Chips Autocomplete** component for the 1st time it shows the drop down and if 
I select any option from the dropdown and again touched the **Chips Autocomplete** component field its not showing dropdown until we type something.Can't we change this default behaviour?

and one more issue is,If I type something in the search field and hit enter it is displaying that data in the screen.**I want to display the data present only in the list**. Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-jzywqh?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.ts) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put only available players:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-vanj4a)

```
  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;
    // Add our fruit
    if ((value || '').trim() && this.allFruits.indexOf(value) > -1) {
      this.fruits.push(value.trim());
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }

    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
  }
```

Comment: I need one more help for this question ,Here is the new question.can you answer this question? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196269/to-display-the-dropdown-below-the-button-in-chips-autocomplete-component`

Answer (score 1):

use `blur()` for that

```
  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.fruits.push(event.option.viewValue);
    this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
    this.fruitInput.nativeElement.blur()
  }
```